# How to place sibling img/div on top of each other with identical size if parent has padding

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have an image with a div that covers the image exactly. I can get the div to overlay the image by using `position: relative` in the parent and `position: absolute` for the div, but `background-color` fills out the padding in the parent so they aren't overlayed properly.

Here's a snippet that demonstrates the problem.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image" src="https://cards.scryfall.io/normal/front/4/f/4f3deefe-28bc-4e45-a0a0-ab03167e2e81.jpg?1561942156">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

I'm able to get it pretty close with some `calc()`'s to subtract the padding. This almost works, but the `div` fills out a little too much at the bottom. I'd like to not have a bunch of hardcoded values for padding anyway, so I wouldn't really like this solution even if it did work entirely.

Here's a snippet that shows the `calc()` approach.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 2 * 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 2 * 10px);
  border-radius: 13px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image" src="https://cards.scryfall.io/normal/front/4/f/4f3deefe-28bc-4e45-a0a0-ab03167e2e81.jpg?1561942156">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Done. I just copied the fiddles into snippets. Hopefully that's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet does things a slightly different way, putting the img inside the overlay div and putting the actual green, lower opacity overlay as the overlay div's after pseudo element.

This way you don't have to build in any knowledge of the parent's padding.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  height: fit-content;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.overlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.2;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay"> <img class="image" src="https://cards.scryfall.io/normal/front/4/f/4f3deefe-28bc-4e45-a0a0-ab03167e2e81.jpg?1561942156"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using HTML5, browser adds some padding to the bottom of the `img` tag. This can be avoided by making the image a block element. So just adding `display: block` to class `.image` and then it good.

And btw, to define witdh/height of an absolute element, beside `calc()` you can also define 4 values `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` of it.

```css
:root {
  --custom-padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: var(--custom-padding);
  width: 40%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 13px;
  bottom: var(--custom-padding);
  right: var(--custom-padding);
  left: var(--custom-padding);
  top: var(--custom-padding);
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image" src="https://cards.scryfall.io/normal/front/4/f/4f3deefe-28bc-4e45-a0a0-ab03167e2e81.jpg?1561942156">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to parameterize the padding across the `parent` and `overlay` classes? I would like it if I didn't have to remember to change the value everywhere if I update it, especially if I have to do that in code for some reason.

Comment: Well yeah. You can pre-define a variable in `:root` and use it whenever needed, easier to edit - edit in the `:root` and it updated everywhere it used, something like writing sass code. Updated the code above, you can try it again.